# Confusion about trigonometric error bounds in numerical analysis

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a link to a paper on a solution below

http://math.berkeley.edu/~zworski/128/psol07.pdf

For problem 7, the author of the paper does something like so:

$$f''(\xi) = -5e^{2\xi}sin3\xi + 12e^{2x}cos3\xi $$

and to find the upper bound of this function:

$$|f''(\xi)| = |-5e^{2\xi}sin3\xi + 12e^{2x}cos3\xi| \le e^4(5+12)$$

This is the leap of logic I get lost at.

What it appears is they're using the property that both $sin\xi$ and $cos\xi$ are strictly bounded by 1 from above over all real numbers. Okay, I get that part.

The question is, what they're assuming here feels like there's a point on the graph where $sin\xi$ *and* $cos\xi$ are both 1. I dont think this is possible to have them both 1 at the same time. The $e^4$ part is clear because $e$ is increasing. So since the trigonometric functions are 1 at different places it feels like you could get a better bound on it by actually figuring out where the function is maximized. But everywhere I read states "this isn't necessary".

Could someone explain how they're able to jump to this conclusion in general when analyzing these? Why wouldn't they go for a tighter error bound? This would clear up alot of problems for me. It makes it difficult to check my work against stuff because even though I come up with one bound and someone comes up with another, neither are necessarily wrong.

edit: Also, if someone could explain the second solution they came up with (how they got that bound) I would really appreciate it.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you missed the crucial piece from this: $0 \lt \xi \lt 2$.  Now use the triangle inequality, i.e., $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$.  Finally, the $e^{2 x}$ should be $e^{2 \xi}$.  Then we have

$$e^{2 \xi} (-5 \sin{3 \xi} + 12 \cos{3 xi}| \le e^{2 \xi} (|-5 \sin{3 \xi}| + |12 \cos{3 \xi}|$$

$e^{3 \xi}$ is a monotonically increasing function, so $e^{2 \xi} \lt e^2$ because $\xi \lt 2$.  Also, $|\sin{3 \xi}|$ and $|\cos{3 \xi}|$ are each $\le 1$ always.  Then

$$e^{2 \xi} (-5 \sin{3 \xi} + 12 \cos{3 \xi}| \le e^4(5 + 12)$$

as asserted.

Comment: Ah this makes sense, but doesn't this imply the case both sin and cos are 1 at the same time? I guess I'm having trouble seeing how you could argue this is the "real" upper bound.

Comment: @John: sine and cosine are bounded by one, period.  You could try to figure out the "real" upper bound by setting the derivative to zero, etc., but the point of this inequality is that a) it's true, and b) it's a very simple estimate that requires almost no work. And c), it's useful, for which I cannot vouch because I haven't read the other parts of that paper.